# My UIButton is not getting drawn to the screen

Tags: objective-c, button, user-interface, opengl-es, simulator

I am trying to actually test out how to hard code interfaces just using the single view template Xcode provides for now.

I have given AppDelegate.h an ivar and property of UILabel *titleLabel; and my AppDelegate.m code is declared in the -(void) did finish launching:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Set the view controller as the window's root view controller and display.
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;

    UIButton *button                  = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.titleLabel.font            = [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 12];
    button.titleLabel.lineBreakMode   = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
    button.titleLabel.shadowOffset    = CGSizeMake (1.0, 0.0);


    [self.window addSubview: button];

}
```

I get a successful compile, but the button is not drawn on the screen--I just get the standard blank template running in the simulator. How do I get it to draw?

Answer (score 1):

Your window appears to be uninitialized, and your function is returning too early.  Try this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds]];
    // Set the view controller as the window's root view controller and display.
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    UIButton *button                  = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button.titleLabel.font            = [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 12];
button.titleLabel.lineBreakMode   = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
button.titleLabel.shadowOffset    = CGSizeMake (1.0, 0.0);


[self.window addSubview: button];
return YES;
}
```

Remember that `return` immediately exits a function, and any code below it will not be executed.

Comment: I don't think the window needs to be initialized. The only problem was the code after the `return` statement!

Comment: @typicalFlow could you expand on that statement? I am getting this new code to compile, but the button still isn't showing up!

Comment: @GPP Codafi has already expanded on that. I was merely suggesting that allocation of `window` need not be done because the nibs take care of that. Did the change suggested by CodaFi not work either?

Comment: @typicalflow: remember that the OP mentioned he was taking a shot at programmatic UI's?  No nibs here.